# Dictionary with untyped pointer as key type

Tags: c#, pointers, dictionary, void

First of all, this is my first question here, so let me know if I'm doing anything wrong.

I'm working on a couple of somewhat complicated C# scripts for Unity, and currently I need a Dictionary mapping from pointers of unknown types to object instances of types depending on the type of the key pointer:

```
(void* => MyClass<T>)
```

where T is the type of the target of the key pointer for each entry.

Firstly, how should I specify the key type? void* doesn't seem to be valid.

Secondly, is there an elegant way to specify the type bound? Otherwise I can probably improvise a solution.

Comment: `void *` does not make sense in C#, I'm guessing you mean `object`

Comment: This is a bit complicated for someone who knew so little C# that he thought that `void*` was a good idea.

Comment: How do you know you need this type of dictionary? Do you have a link or something to see?

Comment: Thank for correcting the title! What I'm using it for is fairly esoteric, and I don't want to move too far from the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already discovered pointer types in C# can't be used as the key type of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.  A `IntPtr` value can though and every `void*` is convertible to `IntPtr`.  Hence I would use `Dictionary<IntPtr, MyClass<T>>` and just map the `void*` values into `IntPtr`.

```
unsafe class Container<T> { 
  Dictionary<IntPtr, MyClass<T>> m_map;
  void Add(void* key, MyClass<T> value) { 
    IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)key;
    m_map.Add(ptr, value);
  }

  bool TryGetValue(void* key, out MyClass<T> value) { 
    IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)key;
    return m_map.TryGetValue(ptr, out value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Regarding the second issue, all my methods would have type parameters anyway, so that's not even relevant. In any case, I might use a slightly different approach since I now realize (this sense of) pointers may be too vulnerable, but that's beyond the topic.